# .net issues with pushing data to SugarCRM

Tags: .net, windows, programming-languages, sugarcrm

I have a client writing custom .net apps on their website using soap / API to push data into their SugarCRM professional on-demand account. They are having some trouble with this and have asked the following question, can you please help me with an answer:

I need to know how to retrieve the Authorized Requestors and Server information that are associated with accounts. There is a SugarSoap API command to link the tables before searching but I have been unable to get this to work. An example showing how to use the get_relationships command to retrieve these records would be ideal

This process looks like this in .php:

```
[28] => stdClass Object
(
[name] => accounts_srvip_servers
[type] => link
[relationship] => accounts_srvip_servers
[module] =>
[bean_name] =>
)
```

I think authorized requestors is this one

```
[30] => stdClass Object
(
[name] => accounts_contacts_1
[type] => link
[relationship] => accounts_contacts_1
[module] =>
[bean_name] =>
)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out the CandyWrapper project, which provides a .NET interface to SugarCRM

http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2011/08/10/web-services-in-your-own-language-part-6-candywrapper-for-net/